# Day of the week function in SAS

Tags: function, date, sas

Is there an inbuilt function in SAS that gives the text day of the week? Such as Monday, Tuesday etc from a date variable?

So far, I have just found the [weekday](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0gjyqp85484vpn1cnz3prseelxb.htm) function, that just gives the date as a number from 1-7.

Comment: **DOWNAMEw.** See: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000200842.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get a text day of the week from a date, you can use **DOWNAME.** format.

```
data _null_;
    result = put(today(), dowName.);
    put result=;
run;
```

If you want to get a weekday name from a weekday number, I do not know specific function, which does it, but you can use the fact that 1-7 are also dates and 0 is Friday, 1st January 1960 and add 2 to your number:

```
data _null_;
    do day = 1 to 7;
        weekDay = put(day + 2, dowName.);
        put weekDay=;
    end; 
run;
```

Which will give you:

```
 weekDay=Monday
 weekDay=Tuesday
 weekDay=Wednesday
 weekDay=Thursday
 weekDay=Friday
 weekDay=Saturday
 weekDay=Sunday
```